# How to encode unicode characters with the pattern "\u{<alphanumerical>}" for older browsers in a webpack 4 build?

Tags: javascript, webpack, minify, webpack-4

I need to make our site accessible to Chrome 41 and IE11. However minification introduced some unicode characters that cause no trouble at all in newer browsers but causing "Illegal token" and "Expected hexadecimal digit" errors in the before mentioned browsers.

See this shortened code from the minified bundle:

```
return e.export = { Afr:"\u{1d504}" }
```

This corresponds to `Unicode Character 'MATHEMATICAL FRAKTUR CAPITAL A' (U+1D504)` also known as . However it is considered illegal token in Chrome 41 (the one used in GoogleBot) and IE11 (users with Windows 8.x who never downloaded Chrome or Firefox).

Is there any webpack plugin or transformation tool, that encodes these values differently?

We currently use `UglifyJS` plugin for our minification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I didn't fix this problem but I realized that the version `"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.3.0",` was set to encode these characters (coming most likely from `react-html-parser`).

See the config I have removed to make it work with browsers.

```
new UglifyJsPlugin({
    uglifyOptions: {
      output: {
          // This was turned in the app because "emoji and regex" values 
          // were not minified properly, citing this issue:
          // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2488
          // However, the issue was solved a long time ago and this just broke
          // the site for IE11 and Chrome 41/GoogleBot
          ascii_only: true,
        },
      },
    }),
```